# Azure Service Fabric nodes, node types, instances and scale sets

Tags: azure-service-fabric

After experimenting with Azure's Service fabric for a few days I still feel uncomfortable with the following four key words:
 * instance
 * node
 * node type
 * scale set.

What do they mean? What are the differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Instance**: Depends on the context - it could mean a VM, an instance of a service, etc.

**Node**: A node within the cluster - in an Azure deployment right now that would mean a VM, but if you're running the dev environment on your box, then a node is really a set of processes.

**Node type**: Defines the size and other properties of a VM type. Each node type in a cluster has to be a separate VM scale set.

**Scale set**: A set of VMs managed as one.

Some useful resources:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal/

Answer (score 5):

A SF cluster consists of a group or a ring of VMs (sometimes called "nodes") that talk or knows each other which is taken care of for you by the SF framework(consider SF as platform as a service)

A SF app consists of microservices. So your solution structure will contain :

- The SF App project which contains the application manifests, deploy scripts
- Microservices projects (can be an actors, stateful or stateless services)

When the SF app gets deployed, those microservices will get installed in the VMs. So you now have an "instance" of those microservices. If you have 5 VMs in the cluster, in the case of stateless microservices, those will be deployed to those 5 VMs.

For stateful microservices, one VM will be elected as the primary and two will be assigned as secondary.