# Local dev 5 node service fabric, with 2 frontend and 3 backend nodes

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'd like to configure my Service Fabric installation with 2 frontend and 3 backend nodes, so I can more closely replicate my production environment.

I've followed the steps in this post:

[Azure Service Fabric nodes, node types, instances and scale sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617633/azure-service-fabric-nodes-node-types-instances-and-scale-sets)

But it seems that the config has changed a bit since this was written. If I edit the config anyway I get the error:

> Dev
>   Cluster size 2 is not supported. Size should be either 1 or 5.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to have a local 5 node cluster with 2 frontend and 3 backend nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster):

> When developing applications, you often find yourself doing quick
>   iterations of writing code, debugging, changing code, and debugging.
>   To help optimize this process, the local cluster can run in two modes:
>   one-node or five-node. Both cluster modes have their benefits.
>   Five-node cluster mode enables you to work with a real cluster. You
>   can test failover scenarios, work with more instances and replicas of
>   your services. One-node cluster mode is optimized to do quick
>   deployment and registration of services, to help you quickly validate
>   code using the Service Fabric runtime.

So, for the dev cluster, you can't use 2 node types.

For the production cluster, you can have 2 node types. 
However, for production workloads, you should run at least [5 primary nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes), for failover and DR purposes.

What you can do is use [placement constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#node-properties-and-placement-constraints) to designate frontend and backend services.
Please keep in mind that this restricts options for SF to balance workloads.

Comment: The local development cluster can have more than five nodes, but since all of the nodes are running in the same machine, each node is a different node type. This is because endpoints are configured at the node type level and to avoid port conflicts on the same machine each node must be of different node type. As mentioned in the previously you can add placement properties to designate frontend and backend nodes in both dev and production environment.